# batch file programming with delimiters

Tags: batch-file

the below code gives an output of which is expected.

```
20152210
0242 AM
```

the code is :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE=%%k%%j%%i
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:." %%i in ('time /t') do set TIME=%%i%%j%%k

echo %DATE%
echo %TIME%
```

I don't understand the part `delims=/ "` and `delims=:."` where two characters are used as delimiters which is in turn giving a proper output.

Could anyone explain me the part `delims=/ "` and `delims=:."`?

Comment: Note that `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` are reserved environment variables.  Though your code may work just fine, it's somewhat poor practice to use these as variables in your batch file.

Comment: take a look at the output of `date /t` and `time /t` and it might be clearer why the delimiters are needed.

Answer (score 0):

The delims command can use more than one character, for example, 'abcd+efg+hijk;lmno;pqr' can be broken up using "delims=;+" (from [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)) So here the two characters can be used both, when they are reached. Either one, or another, in different parts. For example, time can be written like 22:03.30 or 22.03:30, and they work. Space and slash with date, and : or . with time.

As a comment suggests, it is better to use non-system vars for your own code:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set MYDATE=%%k%%j%%i
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:." %%i in ('time /t') do set MYTIME=%%i%%j%%k

echo %MYDATE%
echo %MYTIME%
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you should also mention that consecutive delimiters are treated as a single separator; for instance, when having defined `tokens=1,2 delims=,;`, `abc,;,,def` will return two parts `abc` and `def`...

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to understand the somewhat arcane syntax of the `for` command.  If you're going to be writing a lot of batch files, get used to looking at the `for` command's help at `for /?`.  Wanton abuse of the `for` command is how you get a lot of things done with batch.

So, let's look at the first command:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set MyDATE=%%k%%j%%i
```

I'm just going to cover the `delims` option.  This option specifies what delimiters to look for in the values specified in the command `'date /t'`.  In other words, it's how you tell the for command where the tokens are.  Notice that it's at the end of the options list?  That seems kind of strange, but it's actually important.  Since the delimiter is allowed to be the space character, you put at at the end of the options list.  That way, it's not ambiguous.  So, here, the delimiters are the space () and the forward slash (`/`).

The output for `date /t` is like this:

```
Wed 10/21/2015
```

[Note that I'm using US English region, so my dates are in M/D/Y format.]

The delims option splits the output on any delimiter characters.  Each resulting "token" is assigned to a variable beginning with the variable you specify in the `for` command.  You specified `%%i` here, so the first token is `%%i`, then `%%j` and so on.  If you specified this:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a ....
```

Then the tokens would begin with `%%a`, then `%%b`, etc.

The `tokens=2,3,4` part tells the for command which tokens to assign to variables.  This will make the `for` command actually assign the variables.

So for our command here, the tokens are like this:

```
Token | Value | Variable
------|-------|---------
   1  |   Wed |  None
   2  |    10 |  %%i
   3  |    21 |  %%j
   4  |  2015 |  %%k
```

Note that the delimiters do not appear in the output!

That makes the `do` section of the command change from this:

```
set MyDATE=%%k%%j%%i
```

To this:

```
set MyDATE=20152110
```

Now, I don't know why you want your dates in Y/D/M format, but I'm assuming your region uses D/M/Y and you're converting to Y/M/D.

---

**Edit to add:**

You state that this code, removing the space:

```
@echo off 
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/" %%i in ('date /t') do set MyDATE=%%k%%j%%i 
echo %MYDATE% 
pause
```

Produces this output:

```
2015 28
```

The answer is that, without the space, the first token becomes `Wed 28`.  However, you also told the `for` command `tokens=2,3,4`, so you want `%%i` to be the second token, `%%j` the third, and `%%k` the fourth token.  That means your table looks like this:

```
Token | Value  | Variable
------|--------|---------
   1  | Wed 10 |  None
   2  |     28 |  %%i
   3  |  2015  |  %%j
   4  |        |  %%k
```

Note that `%%j` gets the value `2015` with a space on the end of it.  That's because that's how `date /t` outputs.  For whatever reason, it has a trailing space after the year.  You can see more clearly by running this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/" %%i in ('date /t') do (
    echo "%%i"
    echo "%%j"
    echo "%%k"
)
```

Which generates this output (again, US English so dates are m/d/y):

```
"27"
"2015 "
""
```

Also note that there is no token 4.  When `/` is the delimiter, there's only two delimiters in `Wed 10/28/2015`, so token 4 is an empty value.  You can still make `for` assign it, but it isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Hi,

First of all thanks for explaining me. But when I remove space I am getting the following output.  

@echo off 

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/" %%i in ('date /t') do set MyDATE=%%k%%j%%i

echo %MYDATE%

pause

ouput is --> 2015 28

could u pls explain me why is it like this time?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a KISS version:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 eol=/ delims=/ " %%A IN ('DATE /t') DO (
    SET dd=%%B 
    SET mm=%%C
    SET yyyy=%%D
)
```

Output:

```
echo %dd%
echo %mm%
echo %yyyy%

12
13
2021
```